# android выделить картинку в GridView

Tags: android

У меня есть простой GridView с простым адаптером.

[image]

Все кнопки имеют ClickListener.

Мне нужно, выбрать изображение, на которое я нажал:

так: [image] или так: [image]

в зависимости от условия в ClickListener"е:

```
if(условие1){selection color = color1}; 

if(условие2){selection color = color2};
```

Если у кого то есть идеи или соображения как это сделать, буду рад выслушать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи лучше использовать селекторы состояний.
Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).
Декларативно описываете разные стили для разных состояний кнопки и в лайауте просто указываете в аттрибуте android:background на описанный бэкграунд.
Еще советую поиграться с 9-patch картинками, очень полезный тул для создания масштабируемых графических ресурсов

Comment: У меня цвет селектора должен определятся кодом в блоке онКликЛистенера, а в селекторах состояния цвет нажатия, после освобождения кнопки от нажатия, и дефолтный цвет задаются статически в ХМЛ файле, правильно?

А на счет 9-patch картинок, я о них не слышал, можно ссылку на ресурс для ознакомления?

Comment: Что такое 9-patch и как его применять http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
```

Comment: но как выделить элемент?